# Unable to get search results to filter

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I'm trying to filter the search results of my MySQL database, I am wanting to filter the results by selecting values from two drop down boxes, the first box being Club and the second being Division so I can filter the results by Division and Club.

My issue is that when I make a selection in the club field nothing happens, I can select from the Division field and the results will display the selected division but nothing happens when I select by club.

```
    <?php
include("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Club Search</title>
<style>
.style1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset style="width: 327px"><legend>Filter Results</legend>
<form id="filter" name="filter" method="post" action="search.php" style="width: 316px">
<label for="club">Club</label>
<select name="club">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY club ORDER BY club";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row["club"]."'".($row["club"]==$_REQUEST["club"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["club"]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>

    <label>Division</label>
<select name="division">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY division ORDER BY division";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row["division"]."'".($row["division"]==$_REQUEST["division"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["division"]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />

  <a href="search.php"> 
  reset</a>
</form></fieldset>
<br /><br />
<fieldset style="width: 720px"><legend>Search Results</legend>
<br/>
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="style1"><strong>Division</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="style1"><strong>Club</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="style1"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="style1"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="style1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["club"]='') {
    $search_string = " AND (club LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."%' OR (division LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."%')";  
}
if ($_REQUEST["division"]<>'') {
    $search_division = " AND division='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."'";   
}

if ($_REQUEST["club"]='' and $_REQUEST["division"]='') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE club = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."' AND division = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."'".$search_string.$search_division;
}  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_division;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td class="style1"><?php echo $row['division']?></td>
    <td class="style1"><?php echo $row['club']?></td>
    <td class="style1"><?php echo $row['last_name']?></td>
    <td class="style1"><?php echo $row['first_name']?></td>
    <td class="style1"><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td></tr>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
<br/>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
I changed the following code from this:

```
if ($_REQUEST["club"]='') {
$search_string = " AND (club LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."%' OR (division LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."%')";
```

}

to this:

```
if ($_REQUEST["club"]<>'') {
    $search_club = " AND (club LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."%' OR (club LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."%')";    
}
```

and now it will allow me to filter by club and division but I still can't do just by club alone!

Comment: I highly recommend that you remove all of your database code and put it in functions, then loop over the data from those functions rather than directly looping over the db result

Comment: @Zak how will that help?

Comment: first, if you ever want to get the same data again, you won't have to rewrite the code in a different place... it will be conveniently packaged into a function. second, once the code is in a function, you can write small tests (even use unit tests if you want) to test that your data is retrieving correctly, and third, in a word, maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if ($_REQUEST["club"]='') {
$search_string = " AND (club LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."%' OR (division LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."%')";
```

and this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_division;
```

To this:

```
if ($_REQUEST["club"]<>'') {
    $search_club = " AND club='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."'";   
}
```

And this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_club.$search_division;
```

And it will work!

Comment: @user2587858 no worries!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` operator in your `if` statements, you want to use `==` comparison operator like follows:

```
if ($_REQUEST["club"] == '') {
    $search_string = " AND (club LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."%' OR (division LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."%')";  
}
if ($_REQUEST["division"] <> '') {
    $search_division = " AND division='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."'";   
}

if ($_REQUEST["club"] == '' and $_REQUEST["division"] == '') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE club = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["club"])."' AND division = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["division"])."'".$search_string.$search_division;
}  else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_division;
}
```

Comment: that still doesn't work, making a selection from the club drop down displays all the data in the database now not just the selected club name and now I can't even filter by division